# empty field or blank field or null field is not shown in php code

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code, In employee table there are some records whose pfuidno is null
but it is not showing on server run where is my mistake

```
$sql1="select a.code,a.empname,a.pfuidno from emplmast a ";1
$get1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
$m_no = mysqli_num_rows($get1);
if ($m_no!=0)
{
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($get1))
    {
        if ($row1['pfuidno']=='' OR empty($row1['pfuidno']))
        {
          $m_errmsg='UAN is Blank for Employee Code '.$row1['code'].' Name '.$row1['empname'];
          echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('$m_errmsg')</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `;1`? and `OR` need to be `||`

Comment: Have you tried ```var_dump($row1);``` directly above the ```if ($row1['pfuidno']=='' OR empty($row1['pfuidno']))``` to look at the content of your database result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.remove `1` beside query code line.

2.Use `_assoc()` as you specified column-names in query.(***Not compulsion***, but will give you a lighter associative array)

3.`OR` need to be `||`

4.Checking for `NULL` need to be added

Code need to be:-

```
$sql1="select a.code,a.empname,a.pfuidno from emplmast a "; // remove 1
$get1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
$m_no = mysqli_num_rows($get1);
if ($m_no > 0){
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get1)){ // use _assoc
        if ($row1['pfuidno']=='' || empty($row1['pfuidno']) || $row1['pfuidno'] === NULL){ //check for NULL
            $m_errmsg='UAN is Blank for Employee Code '.$row1['code'].' Name '.$row1['empname'];
            echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('$m_errmsg')</script>";
        }
    }
}
```